# JDBC Connectivity Error using Apache Tomcat Version 7.0

Tags: java, jsp, ms-access, jdbc

I am stuck up with a situation while using apache tomcat version 7. I created a simple index.jsp file in a notepad and wrote the following JDBC code inside scriptlet tag:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:testdsn");

out.println(c);
            Statement stmt = c.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from login");

while(rs.next())
{
    out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

I placed the JSP file parallel to WEB-INF inside a folder named "test" with classes folder and web.xml inside WEB-INF. I created a war file using cmd and deployed it to tomcat.

When I try to run the index.jsp file, it shows errors data source name not found and no default driver specified.

I know why this error comes in Java but this time I'm not able to resolve it.

The problem is I've created the requisite dsn and but still it is not accepting and showing data source name not found.

The stack trace is:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

root cause

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:98)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: What error, post stacktrace.

Comment: My understanding is that the JdbcOdbcDriver is a bridge that still requires an appropriate ODBC driver be present/functional. Have you been able to utilize the ODBC driver successfully outside of java?

Comment: Yes I've used the type1 drivers too but probably you are right bro, it is successfully getting connected to Type4 driver but not to Type1

Comment: Can we not connect MS Access which uses Type1 driver through JDBC code while using Apache Tomcat??

Comment: have you created the data source in your system on which you are running this application?